# Swap partitions on android?

Tags: 4.0-ice-cream-sandwich, cyanogenmod, sd-card, partitions, swap

I just installed [AParted](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.sylkat.AParted) on CyanogenMod 9 (Android 4.0.4,Kernel version 2.6.32.9-FXP) and was trying to partition my SD Card to extend internal memory.
Anyway, I found that it can make swap partitions, I'm familiar with the swap partition concept on linux, but does Android (at least my version or my kernel) support swap partitions? would it be useful or just a waste of space?

Comment: You might wish to check the 10 [questions tagged "swap"](http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/swap?sort=newest). Combining their answers, your question will be answered along. Especially, take a look at [Creating App and Swap partition for Android](http://android.stackexchange.com/q/41146/16575).

Comment: Note that swapping will wear out your flash memory more quickly.